# How to output Get-ADUser as csv without including the fieldnames in the first row using powershell?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am trying to use the Get-ADUser to get a dump of the users in our system, and then output the contents to a CSV file.

However, I have not yet been able to figure out how to exclude the fieldnames from the first row in the csv file.

I want to have just the data [in csv format] but without the header row.

This code produces the data I want:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=My,OU=OrganisationName,OU=Accounts,OU=Groups and Accounts,DC=myorg,DC=com" -Properties * | 
    Sort-Object -Property sn, GivenName, UserPrincipalName | 
        Select-Object name, sn, GivenName, UserPrincipalName | 
            Export-Csv -Path "C:\temp1.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

But it insists on including the header row (despite the -NoTypeInformation flag).

I have tried piping the data through the command:

```
Format-Table  -HideTableHeaders
```

Like so:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=My,OU=OrganisationName,OU=Accounts,OU=Groups and Accounts,DC=myorg,DC=com" -Properties * | 
    Sort-Object -Property sn, GivenName, UserPrincipalName | 
        Select-Object name, sn, GivenName, UserPrincipalName | 
            Format-Table -HideTableHeaders | 
                Export-Csv -Path "C:\temp1.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

But this converts the data in the csv file to gibberish.

Does anyone have any thoughts on how I might get rid of the header row?

thanks heaps,

David :-)

Comment: May I ask why you want to omit the headers? They are actually part of the standard and every standard compliant tool shouldn't have any issue with them. In case you could simply create the file with headers and remove them in a further step later on with `Get-Content | Select-Object -Skip 1`

Comment: thanks Olaf. I need to concatenate the data afterwards with other data sources and dont want header repeated

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem when you use the proper way ...  ;-)  ... you may explain what your actual goal is instead of the way you think you should go to come this goal.

Comment: Thanks Olav, The final aim is that I have to retrieve a list of users from several different OU's in AD and merge them together into a single csv list of users.  For this, I am making several consecutive calls to Get-ADUser [one call for each OU that I need], and then merging the output of each of these calls.  I only want the header row in the first call however.

Comment: If I got this right you don't need *interrmediate* CSV files in such a case. But even if you use them PowerShell will handle them well and will not repeat the headers when you import them in one big chunk and save all data together in a new CSV file. That's what I meant. You may share your actual code - not just the part you think you need and you have problems with. ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `Export-CSV` use `ConvertTo-CSV` skip the first line using `Select-Object -Skip 1` then save the file using `Out-File`

instead of this:

```
 [...]Select-Object name, sn, GivenName, UserPrincipalName | 
            Export-Csv -Path "C:\temp1.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Do:

```
 [...]Select-Object name, sn, GivenName, UserPrincipalName | 
 ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation | Select -Skip 1 |
 Out-File "C:\temp1.csv"
```